# Tab in xterm under KDE always brings up accessibility tool dialog

Tags: kde, desktop, xterm, kdm

Using KDE 4.14.13, Fedora 22, kdm desktop manager, if I type `Tab` to try to do command line completion I get the KDE accessibility tool dialog asking me if I want to enable "Sticky Keys" and "Mouse Keys".  No matter what I answer I can't get this to turn off.  `Tab` works as expected when using `konsole` or `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: That is probably a setting in the KDE accessibility configuration, but I don't see anything there which would do this.

Comment: I just ran into the same questions. It's been a while since you asked this question; in the meantime, have you been able to find an answer, fix, or workaround?